# SoundJS Cordova and WebAudio differences - caching audio files

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, soundjs

So I have a question.
  When using Sound JS and the WebAudio plugin, whenever I `createInstance` for the same audio file a second time, there's no second request being made. So `createInstance` makes a http request for that sound file the first time it is being called, but then, whenever I call `createInstance` again, with the same src, the audio file is taken from cache, and no useless requests are being made.

This is great. However, when using the Cordova plugin, it seems that `createInstance` always makes a request for the audio file. It is never cached. I know this because each time the sound is being played, there's a certain delay before audio is heard. The same happens with WebAudio, but only on the initial play, after that, it plays instantly.

I believe this is because, in the Cordova plugin, when calling `createInstance`, `_playbackResource` is always created as `new Media()` , as the documentation says here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html . So I guess there is no internal caching mechanism built in the Cordova Media plugin? So each time you call `new Media(src)`, although the src was already loaded, Android makes a new request to the server each time.

Are these valid points? If so, then, what would be the solution? Should I keep a pool of all instances, when using the Cordova plugin?

Thanks.